# Returns undefined even though return statement is present and variable has a value NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, return

I have a function that primarily has 2 if conditions at the top level. In the `if` and the `else` I tell it to return a value.

Depending on the case different values are returned to the map function.

During debugging I can see that the `if` return does have a value I am expecting but when I log the result of the entire function return values from the `if` are `undefined` while values in the `else` are coming through fine.

The input file for this function can be found here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tBvav0HfGmPep9mbPLkJy6A5WivmWUro/view?usp=sharing

I have been working on this for a whole day and still do not understand why the return for the `else` does work but the `if` does not even though they are similar

```
const fs = require('fs')
const _ = require("lodash")
let fixExtraCodeListsFinal = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("metadata.json").toString())

const test = fixExtraCodeListsFinal.map(fieldObj => {
    if (fieldObj.hasOwnProperty("relations")){
        fieldObjKeys = Object.keys(fieldObj.relations[0])
        let result = {}
        if (fieldObjKeys[0] == "0"){
            codeListDependencies = fieldObj.relations[0][0].codeList.allOf
           const codeListDependentList = codeListDependencies.map(codeListDependenciesObj => {
                if (codeListDependenciesObj.value.listItems){
                    resultDirty = {codeListDependentField: Object.keys(codeListDependenciesObj.attributes)[0], codeListItems: codeListDependenciesObj.value.listItems}
                    result = {codeListDependentField: getParentPath1(resultDirty.codeListDependentField).path, codeListItems: codeListDependenciesObj.value.listItems}
                    //console.log(result)
                }
                else  if (codeListDependenciesObj.value.links[0].href){
                    dependentPath = Object.keys(codeListDependenciesObj.attributes)[0]
                    result = {codeListDependentField: getParentPath1(dependentPath).path, relations: codeListDependenciesObj.value.links[0].href}
                    //THIS IS WHERE U STOPPED WRITING CODE
                    //console.log(result)
                    //console.log('idk what this case is dependencies')
                }
                else{
                    //console.log("unhandled metadata formatting, reach out to CE for a fix")
                }
                return result
        })
        //console.log(codeListDependentList)
        return codeListDependentList
        }
        else{
            fieldObjKeys = Object.keys(fieldObj.relations[0])
            fieldObjKeys.map(key => {
                if (fieldObj.relations[0][key].hasOwnProperty("allOf")){
                    dependentFieldsArr = fieldObj.relations[0][key].allOf
                    dependentFields = dependentFieldsArr.map(dependentFieldsArrObj => Object.keys(dependentFieldsArrObj.attributes))
                }
                else{
                    dependentFields = Object.keys(fieldObj.relations[0][key].oneOf.attributes)
                }
            })
            dependentPathADPFormat = _.flatten(dependentFields)
            dependentPathsCEformat = dependentPathADPFormat.map(getParentPath1)
            uniqueDependencyList = _.uniqBy(dependentPathsCEformat.map(obj => obj.path).map(dependentPath => fieldObj.conditionallyRequired = dependentPath))[0]

            originalFieldObj = fieldObj.vendorPath
            //console.log(JSON.stringify({uniqueDependencyList, originalFieldObj}))
            result = {uniqueDependencyList, originalFieldObj}
           return result

        }
        //this code needs to happen laters
        //fieldObj.conditionallyRequired = uniqueDependencyList[0]

        //console.log(JSON.stringify(fieldObj))
    }
    })
   console.log(test)
```

I have truncated the output here. here is the current output

```
[ undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  { uniqueDependencyList: 'worker.businessCommunication.faxes[*].countryDialing',
    originalFieldObj: 'businessCommunication.faxes[*].areaDialing' },
  undefined,
  { uniqueDependencyList: 'worker.businessCommunication.faxes[*].areaDialing',
    originalFieldObj: 'businessCommunication.faxes[*].dialNumber' },
  undefined,
  { uniqueDependencyList: 'worker.businessCommunication.landlines[*].countryDialing',
    originalFieldObj: 'businessCommunication.landlines[*].areaDialing' },
  undefined,
  { uniqueDependencyList: 'worker.businessCommunication.landlines[*].areaDialing',
    originalFieldObj: 'businessCommunication.landlines[*].dialNumber' },
  undefined,
  undefined,
  { uniqueDependencyList: 'worker.businessCommunication.mobiles[*].countryDialing',
    originalFieldObj: 'businessCommunication.mobiles[*].areaDialing' },
  undefined,
  { uniqueDependencyList: 'worker.businessCommunication.mobiles[*].areaDialing',
    originalFieldObj: 'businessCommunication.mobiles[*].dialNumber' },
  undefined,
  { uniqueDependencyList: 'worker.businessCommunication.pagers[*].countryDialing',
    originalFieldObj: 'businessCommunication.pagers[*].areaDialing' },
  undefined,
  { uniqueDependencyList: 'worker.businessCommunication.pagers[*].areaDialing',
    originalFieldObj: 'businessCommunication.pagers[*].dialNumber' },
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined,
  undefined.......
```

Here is my expected output also truncated

```
{"uniqueDependencyList":"worker.person.governmentIDs[*].nameCode.codeValue.nameCode.codeValue","originalFieldObj":"person.governmentIDs[*].idValue"}
{"uniqueDependencyList":"worker.person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].countryCode","originalFieldObj":"person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].cityName"}
{"uniqueDependencyList":"worker.person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].countryCode","originalFieldObj":"person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].countrySubdivisionLevel1"}
{"uniqueDependencyList":"worker.person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].countryCode","originalFieldObj":""}
{"uniqueDependencyList":"worker.person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].countryCode","originalFieldObj":"person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].countrySubdivisionLevel1.shortName"}
{"uniqueDependencyList":"worker.person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].countryCode","originalFieldObj":"person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].lineOne"}
{"uniqueDependencyList":"worker.person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].countryCode","originalFieldObj":"person.otherPersonalAddresses[*].postalCode"}
{ codeListDependentField:
   'worker.workAssignment.homeOrganizationalUnits[*].typeCode.codeValue',
  relations:
   '/codelists/hr/v3/worker-management/departments/WFN/1?$filter=foreignKey eq {payrollGroupCode}' }
{ codeListDependentField:
   'worker.workAssignment.homeOrganizationalUnits[*].typeCode.codeValue',
  relations: '/codelists/hr/v3/worker-management/business-units/WFN/1' }
{ codeListDependentField:
   'worker.workAssignment.homeOrganizationalUnits[*].typeCode.codeValue',
  codeListItems:
   [ { codeValue: '00-1005-FRM-PA', shortName: 'Non Cert Job' },
     { codeValue: '001000201', shortName: 'NON Cert job' },
     { codeValue: '001101000', shortName: '001101000' },
     { codeValue: '001101AA', shortName: '001101AA' },
     { codeValue: '001101DM', shortName: '001101DM' },
     { codeValue: '001101MA', shortName: '001101MA' }....
```

Comment: Just looking at the code it seems like `fieldObj.hasOwnProperty("relations")` must be coming out `false`

Comment: @catalyst, yes that was part of the problem. As a result I needed to use .filter with that same `fieldObj.hasOwnProperty("relations")` then pass the result only to the function to ensure it is never false. If I complete my solution I will post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fixExtraCodeListsFinal1 = fixExtraCodeListsFinal.filter(fieldObj => fieldObj.hasOwnProperty("relations"))
const dependenciesResultToHydrate = fixExtraCodeListsFinal1.map(fieldObj => {
```

Replace the beginning of the function with above, this will ensure that the main function is never false and returning undefined by filtering for valid values only first